# Node glob to negates global.min-263762536.js

Tags: node.js, gulp

I need to negate minified files from stream source in my Gulpfile:

```
gulp.src([
  'src/*.js'.
  !'src/{glob}'
]);
```

I can't figure out how to match the pattern `.min` in my glob.

Comment: You've got a dot (.) after your first item in the array, I think this should be a comma? Also, the exclamation mark is in the wrong place - So, try something like this: gulp.src([
  'src/*.js',
 '!src/*.min.js'
]);

Comment: @Alex thanks, yes that's right about the dot instead of comma, and yes you are correct that the exclamation mark is not in the right place, it should be inside the string :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to negate pattern `src/global.min-263762536.js`:

```
gulp.src([
  'src/*.js',
  '!src/*.min*.js'
]);
```